# Progressbar update progress while copying

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I want to have a progressbar from TornadoFX which knows its min and max.

The progressbar should be updated by using the information of the Copy thread:

```
 Files.copy(
    sourcePath,
    destinationPath,
    ExtendedCopyOption.INTERRUPTIBLE,
    StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING
)
```

For caluating the max and the current progress i was using the following code:

```
var mb = 1024
var fileSize = sourceFile.length() / mb
for (index in 0..fileSize) {
    updateMessage("Copying")
    updateProgress(index, fileSize)
    if (index == fileSize ) {
        updateMessage("Done"))
    }
}
```

Overall i have sth like that shortened by a lot.

```
button {
    action {
        runAsync {
            Files.copy(
               sourcePath,
               destinationPath,
               ExtendedCopyOption.INTERRUPTIBLE,
               StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING
            )
            var mb = 1024
            var fileSize = sourceFile.length() / mb
            for (index in 0..fileSize) {
                updateMessage("Copying")
                updateProgress(index, fileSize)
                if (index == fileSize ) {
                    updateMessage("Done").get())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

progressbar(status.progress) {
    progress = 0.0
    minWidth = 250.0
    minHeight = 30.0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every async operation will update the default `TaskStatus` model, so basically you can just inject the `TaskStatus` model into your view and bind that to a `ProgressBar`. TaskStatus has observable properties for `running`, `completed`, `message`, `title` and `progress`.

I wrote a short article and created a screencast back when this was implemented, you might find it interesting:

https://edvin.town/tornadofx-runasync-with-taskstatus/

You can also pass in a specific `TaskStatus` instance, or even reuse the pattern used to implement this if needed. See the source code of the framework for implementation details.